# Select both matching and non-matching results in SQL query / subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find items with most similar colors as shorts relative to the total number of colors they have. I could easily first select the match counts, and then for each matching item select separately the total count and then divide, but I would prefer to do this in a single statement if at all possible so is to minimize what would ultimately be hundreds if not thousands of queries.

## Starting Query:

```
SELECT clothes,
        COUNT(clothes.id) AS matches
 FROM clothes
    AND clothes.item!='shorts' 
    AND clothes.colors IN (
        SELECT clothes.colors 
        FROM clothes 
        WHERE item='shorts' 
        DESC LIMIT 5000
    ) 

 GROUP BY item ORDER BY matches DESC
```

## Table Setup:

```
id  | item    | colors
=========================
1   | shorts  | red 
2   | shorts  | blue 
3   | shorts  | green
4   | pants   | red 
5   | pants   | blue
6   | pants   | white
7   | shirts  | red 
8   | shirts  | blue 
9   | shirts  | gray 
10  | shirts  | orange 
11  | shirts  | purple 
12  | shirts  | black 
13  | shirts  | white 
14  | shirts  | tan 
15  | shirts  | fuscia
```

## Goal Output

```
Item   | Matches | Total | Ratio
==================================
pants  | 2       | 3     | 2/3
shirts | 2       | 9     | 2/9
```

Any ideas on how to do this in a single query statement?

Comment: How can you get 2 matches from item pants?

Comment: @RubahMalam They have two of the three available shorts colours.

Comment: Yes, pants share the colors red and blue with shorts. The sub-select would return ('red','blue','green'), which means both pants and shirts would have 2 matches.

Comment: I don't think MySQL accepts the `limit` in the subquery.  Does that really work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To total all, use count. To total the matching ones only, use CASE with SUM:

```
SELECT clothes.Item, SUM(
        CASE WHEN clothes.
                colors IN (
                    SELECT clothes.
                        colors
                    FROM clothes
                    WHERE item = 
                        'shorts' DESC 
                        LIMIT 5000
                    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    Matches, COUNT(clothes.
        id) AS matches, CAST(SUM
        (CASE WHEN clothes.
                    colors IN (
                        SELECT clothes
                            .colors
                        FROM clothes
                        WHERE item = 
                            'shorts' 
                            DESC LIMIT 
                            5000
                        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                END) AS VARCHAR) + 
    '/' + CAST(COUNT(clothes.
            id) AS VARCHAR) AS 
    Ratio
FROM clothes clothes.item != 
    'shorts'
```

Comment: Wow, I have never seen the CASE option before! I will give this a shot!